# I've had my home brew sitting at 19c for 4 days now but there are no bubbles

Tags: fermentation, airlock

I've had by home brew sitting at 19c for 4 days now but there are no bubbles showing in the air Lock I opened the lid slightly to look inside I can see the yeast floating on top and there's a fairly strong smell of beer. Do I need to do anything or just leave it.

Comment: Describe "floating" you see krausen or dry yeast like you just pitched a dry pack?

Comment: It was Krause. I took the gravity reading and it came out at 1.012 so I've transferred it into the pressure barrel now. The seal around the rubber on the lid of my fermentation bucket had part of it missing so I think that's probably where the co2 was escaping through.

Comment: Seems about right. i brewed a beer this week with an OG of 1.050. After two days at 68 was down to 1.01 and activity essentially done.

Answer (score 2):

Take a gravity reading. Write down the gravity. Is it already in a reasonable range for a finished beer? Anything of 1.014 or lower should be fine.

Did you take a reading of the Original Gravity (OG)? Is the new gravity reading different? If yes, your yeast is working. If there is no change between the OG and the current gravity, your yeast may be dead. You should pitch another yeast.

The yeast may have died if you pitched it when the wort was too hot or if the yeast was uite too old or improperly stored.

Comment: This is my first time making a home brew so I just followed the instructions on the beer kit and there was no mention of taking an OG reading. I'll take one no tho and se hat comes up if it's high I'll look into getting new yeast. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything.

Airlock activity is also a measure of how well your bucket/carboy/barrel/etc is pressure-sealing.

If there's yeast activity (foam, bubbles, etc.) and a beery-aroma, it's going well.

I would wait 2 weeks before doing anything.  I expect you could then take a gravity reading and find the beer is finished.  If you really want to, take a reading at 1 week.  But be sure keep everything sanitary.

Also, if it's 4 days in and there was no yeast (not pitched, or no vitality), it would probably be already colonised by something nasty anyway.